# WhatsApp logged me out on device - is it a security concern?

Tags: whatsapp

I went to bed last night, and put my Android phone into Airplane mode, something I do pretty regularly at night, except when I'm on call.

However, this morning my WhatsApp popped up telling me that I'm no longer registered on that device (I'm not sure about the exact wording) and I should register my device again. I did that, received the SMS with the verification code, and all my messages were there. I was also logged out from all my web/desktop clients.

I have never encountered this before, and I'm using WhatsApp for more than six years. Should I be concerned? Might it be that someone used my WhatsApp in the meanwhile, possibly restored my backed up messages?